# asp.net decimal multiplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013

So i have an issue my multiplication will work perfectly with full numbers however when i try to use decimal numbers it crys and throws a temper tantrum here is the error log:

Input string was not in a correct format.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error:

```
Line 15:     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 16:     { 
Line 17:         int p = Convert.ToInt32(HourlyWage.Text); 
Line 18:         int q = Convert.ToInt32(HoursPerWeek.Text); 
Line 19:         int t = p * q;
```

that is also the actual method of me multiplying the data, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

If you are entering a `decimal` number, then you should use that type instead of `int`. Use `Convert.ToDecimal`, `decimal.Parse` or safer option [`decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the number like:

```
decimal hourlyWage;

if(decimal.TryParse(HourlyWage.Text, out hourlyWage))
{
 //valid decimal number
}
else
{
 //invalid input
}
```

Do the same for `HoursPerWeek` and then store the result of multiplication in a `decimal` type variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't parse numbers with decimals to an `int`.  Try using `decimal` instead:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    decimal p = Convert.ToDecimal(HourlyWage.Text); 
    decimal q = Convert.ToDecimal(HoursPerWeek.Text); 
    decimal t = p * q;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a decimal string into an integer.

Change the `int`'s into `double`'s or `decimal`s

```
Line 15:     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 16:     { 
Line 17:         decimal p = Convert.ToDecimal(HourlyWage.Text); 
Line 18:         decimal q = Convert.ToDecimal(HoursPerWeek.Text); 
Line 19:         decimal t = p * q;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** You are parsing decimal value as `Integer`.

**Solution :** You need to properly pasre the `decimal` value using any one of the following methods.

```
decimal.Parse()  
decimal.TryParse()   
Convert.ToDecimal()
```

Try This: with `decimal.Parse()`

```
decimal p = decimal.Parse(HourlyWage.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
decimal q = decimal.Parse(HoursPerWeek.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```